# Which adjective should I use with the word "accuracy"?

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing a scientific paper, and I want to know what is the best adjective to use with the word "accuracy" in the following sentence:

> "... the method A has ____ accuracy when compared to method B".

Should I use a) better, b) higher, c) greater, or d) another adjective?

Here I am using the word accuracy to refer the closeness as a technical term, with the meaning of "the degree to which the result of a measurement is close to the correct value."

EDIT:
Adding more context.

I am writing a statistical paper. In this paper, I am comparing two estimation methods in a simulation study. In that simulation study, I have a true value of an parameter, and I am comparing that value with the value obtained (called the estimate) with each method.In this context, accuracy refers to how close the estimate is to the actual value.

Comment: method A is **more accurate** than method B. Use the adjective, not the noun, in English. Spanish and Portuguese and French would use the noun: The accuracy of A is greater than B. You are probably being influenced by one of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While "better," "greater," and "higher" all work here, there is a much simpler way of saying this:

> method A is more accurate than method B.

(This is correct even if you are using the word "accuracy" in the technical, scientific sense.)

Answer (score -1):

The adjectives all have slightly different meanings. Without more context it is impossible to say which is best.
**better** implies that the method A was possibly using better equipment or technique or it was somehow less prone to inaccuracies and external influences.
**higher** implies that the result had less error tolerance, for example +/-1% instead of +/-5%
**greater** is similar to **higher**

Comment: Actually, it sounds like the poster is making the usual [scientific distinction](https://www.google.com/search?q=accuracy+vs+precision) between **accuracy** (closeness to the correct value) and **precision** (degree of uncertainty or repeatability), so no adjective applied to **accuracy** would properly say anything about error tolerance. If you wanted to imply less error tolerance, you would say **higher precision**.